# Python 2.7.3: Copying symlinks, but don't follow

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, symlink

I'm using Python 2.7.3. I'm working on a Python script to copy parts of a directory tree from one location to another. Some of the files that need to be copied are symlinks.

How can I use Python to copy symlinks from location to another without following them? (I just want it to blindly copy them just like they are 'regular' files)

I found that `shutil.copy()` for Python 3.3 supports the argument `follow_symlinks=False`, yet older versions of shutil doesn't.

EDIT: More details:

The purpose of this script is to take all files from a specified location and split them up into individual archives. I know I could do this by zipping up the entire directory and splitting the archive, but I need to have the capability of extracting each archive individually without rejoining into one large archive. Also, each archive must be less than a specified size.

Basic approach:

1. Get all absolute paths to all files of source directory
2. Get all sizes of all files
3. Sort all files (regardless of location) by size
4. Copy files from location X to tmp location (until sum of copied files is <= to max archive size)
5. Create archive of tmp
6. Clean tmp location
7. Go back to 4 while there are still files to copy

Any feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying parts of a directory tree, you say? In that case, try [`shutil.copytree()`](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree).

> If symlinks is true, symbolic links in the source tree are represented as symbolic links in the new tree, but the metadata of the original links is NOT copied; if false or omitted, the contents and metadata of the linked files are copied to the new tree.

So as long as you don't need to keep the metadata the same, this should work just fine (actually, can symlinks on their own even have such metadata, or do they just reference the metadata of the file/object they point to?). Also note that you don't have to copy the entire tree with `copytree()`; the `ignore` argument allows you to provide a callable that will prune down the files and directories to copy.

One thing to watch out for, though: If you modify the contents list passed in to the `ignore` callable, that will also affect what is copied (as you can see in [the `copytree()` source code](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html#copytree-example)).

---

(Copying/paraphrasing from comments)

As the implementation of `shutil.copytree()` shows how `copytree()` handles symbolic links (`linkto = os.readlink(srcname); os.symlink(linkto, dstname)`), that can be used as a reference for how to "copy" symbolic links even if `copytree()` itself is not useful.

Comment: I've added more details to my question. I don't think `shutil.copytree()` will work for the way my solution is currently designed.

Comment: Perhaps not, but the implementation of `copytree()` I linked shows you how `copytree()` handles symbolic links when `simlinks` is true. Why not use that as a reference? You could just wrap `shutil.copy()` or `shutil.copy2()` with your own copy method that adds those few extra lines from `shutil.copytree()` and use that.

Comment: It looks as if shutil.copytree() uses `linkto = os.readlink(srcname)` followed by `os.symlink(linkto, dstname)`. Which is basically what I did as my 'work around'! I guess that means it's the way to do it.

Comment: Should I mark this as answer since the comments contain the answer? Or would it be better to add answer separately?

Comment: Edited my answer to include (most of) the relevant lines of code from `copytree()`.